# How to fix beamer problem after Tex Live Update on 2022-05-17

Tags: beamer

After todays TL package update Beamer does not compile any more – even the simplest document. Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello world
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty:322: Undefine
d control sequence.
<argument> ...{subsubsection}\addtobeamertemplate 
                                                  {theorem begin}{\expandaft...
l.322 }{}
```

No output is generated. Any other document class works fine – given the frame environment is commented out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be fixed tomorrow.

As a work-around either revert the last hyperref update with tlmgr or add this before \documentclass:

```
\makeatletter \def\NR@nopatch@beamer{} \makeatother
```

It will suppress the nameref patch and the error.

Comment: Problem solved by setting back latest hyperref update. Many thanks for the quick solution.

Addendum: The two suggested work-arounds do not behave the same way. The patch before \documentclass removes the error indeed, but leaves \nameref calls in the frame title empty. Maybe this is the intended goal.

Comment: @Franklin yes, suppressing the patch also disables nameref, so it is only a temporary solution. But it  can be easier that reverting a package installation.  Both should no longer be needed both beamer and hyperref have been updated and no longer error.

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer: Everything works fine now. Thanks