# Undefined control sequence.\n\\set@color ->\\special {color push \\current@color \n" with beamer

Tags: beamer

I updated the packages via tlmgr, then when I run the example code in the texdoc with vscode, the recipe would terminate with error. There does exist a pdf, but the first page is strange and the content can not exist if there is a command \tableofcontends. Here's the code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\section[]{}
\begin{frame}{Contents}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \section{1}
    \frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
    \framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.}
    \begin{theorem}
    There is no largest prime number.
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item<1-| alert@1> Suppose $p$ were the largest prime number.
    \item<2-> Let $q$ be the product of the first $p$ numbers.
    \item<3-> Then $q+1$ is not divisible by any of them.
    \item<1-> Thus $q+1$ is also prime and greater than $p$.\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{proof}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And here's the information

```
[{
    "resource": "/d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemisc.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined control sequence.\n\\set@color ->\\special {color push \\current@color \n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 158,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 158,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemisc.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined control sequence.\n\\set@color ->\\special {color push \\current@color \n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 158,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 158,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemisc.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined control sequence.\n\\set@color ->\\special {color push \\current@color \n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 158,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 158,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemisc.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined control sequence.\n\\set@color ->\\special {color push \\current@color \n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 158,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 158,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined control sequence.\n<argument> ...{subsubsection}\\addtobeamertemplate \n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 322,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 322,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Missing \\begin{document}.\n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 322,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 322,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined control sequence.\n<argument> ...expandafter {\\inserttheoremaddition \n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 322,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 322,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Command \\beamer@descriptionitem undefined.\n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 322,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 322,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined control sequence.\n<argument> ...{subsubsection}\\addtobeamertemplate \n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 322,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 322,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Missing \\begin{document}.\n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 322,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 322,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined control sequence.\n<argument> ...expandafter {\\inserttheoremaddition \n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 322,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 322,
    "endColumn": 65536
},
{
    "resource": "/d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Command \\beamer@descriptionitem undefined.\n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 322,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 322,
    "endColumn": 65536
}]
```

Comment: try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644539/2388

Comment: Thanks a lot!@ Ulrike Fischer